# Yii framework, create model , view and add to sitecontroller

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am using Yii framework basic template which I downloaded from here 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/releases/download/2.0.6/yii-basic-app-2.0.6.tgz‌​

Hello I have database named **cosmos** and table named **couto**

```
Database: cosmos
Table: couto
id         int(11) 
firstname   text
lastname    text
```

I created a model called Cosmos.php which is located **/models/Cosmos.php**

```
<pre>
<br />
start php tag
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;


class Cosmos extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'couto';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            ['firstname'],
            ['lastname'],

         ];
    }}end php tag
</pre>
```

---

in **controllers/SiteController.php** I added this

```
    ---Existing code
        public function actionCosmos()
        {
            $model = new Cosmos();

                    $model->id = 1;
                    $model->idnum = "1";
                    $model->name = "1";
                    $model->save();
        }
```

I want to insert data in the table shown in the image and create view saying "records added" or "not added"

Thank you

Comment: try generating with `gii`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make a view like this:

**commos.php:**

```
...
<h1><?php echo $status; ?></h1>
...
```

Then, in your controller:

```
  public function actionCosmos()
    {
        $status = false;
        $model = new Cosmos();
        $model->id = 1;
        $model->idnum = "1";
        $model->name = "1";
        if($model->save())
             $status = true;
        $this->render("commos", array(
              "status" =>$status
        ));

    }
```